# How to stick a null on the end of a char* string in C

Tags: c

```
char* s = (char*)malloc(5);
```

Some processing to add variable number of bytes (numeric) to string.  Eg
    *s = 50;

I now need to null terminate the string.  This works.

```
*(s+1) = 0;
```

But is there a more elegant way?

Based on comments this looks like way to do it

```
char* getvalue(char* str) {
   while((*str++ = getnextchar()) != 'H')
      ;

   *str = '\0'; /* null terminate */

   return str;
}
```

Comment: Can you show your actual code?

Comment: If * s is realy a string I would write '\0' instead of 0 to show that I append a null *char*. I would also increment s on each append (to preseve the "s points to the next free byte" invariant: "* s++ = 50;". Hence the append-zero would be * s = '\0'; Whether tis is more elegant than your code is a matter of taste.

Comment: **don't cast the return value of malloc()!**

Answer (score 2):

Use `calloc` instead of `malloc`. This sets the memory to zeros.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you already put something in `s[0]` as your "string", you just simply terminate like so:

```
s[1] = '\0';
```

However, if you post a more thorough code example, most likely there's generally a better way to copy a string into your new buffer.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming ASCII, you can do this:

```
snprintf(s = malloc(5), 5, "%s", "2");
```

The use of `snprintf` is just to make sure your source string won't overrun your target buffer, and it always results in a `\0` terminated string in `s`.

If you must use an integer constant (or it is not ASCII):

```
snprintf(s = malloc(5), 5, "%c", 50);
```

Your proposed routine does not check to see if the input would overrun the `str` buffer. The API should accept a size parameter, so you can check to make sure to not write more bytes than you should. If you want to return the end of the string, you can do that in another parameter to the function. Then you can allow the function to return an indication whether the terminating character has been seen or not.

```
int getvalue (char *str, size_t sz, char **endp) {
   char *end = str;
   while (--sz > 0)
      if ((*end++ = getnextchar()) == 'H') break;
   *end = '\0'; /* null terminate */
   if (endp) *endp = end;
   return end[-1] == 'H';
}
```

Comment: Ugly, but +1 only for not casting malloc.

Comment: @H2CO3: I believe the question was about how to set `s` in a way so that it is always `\0` terminated. Both the `calloc` answer and `strncpy`/`strcpy` answer can result in either buffer overrun or overwriting the last byte in `s` resulting in an unterminated string.

Comment: @user315052 How can calloc result in a buffer overrun? Are you talking about copying data to it later?

Comment: @James: Yes. Just making sure the buffer is `\0` initialized isn't enough to ensure that it will be `\0` terminated after the data is copied.

Answer (score 0):

Filling zeros(0) and terminating with a NULL('\0') are two different things. If you want to just fill in zeros, use memset after malloc or just use calloc.

If you want your string to be automatically terminated with a NULL, use strcpy/strncpy to copy data into it. This function will copy your data and add the terminating NULL.